# Moodle Installation

Tags: moodle

When I install Moodle using Fantastico I cant seem to create courses.

Does anyone know if there is a problem with Moodle 2.0.2 when installed through fantastico?

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but I am going around in circles.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following bash commands to change permissions of the two moodle dirs. 777 is a little bit unsafe, but it's a fast way to check if the permissions are your problem.

```
sudo chmod 777 -Rvf moodle
sudo chmod 777 -Rvf moodledata
```

Answer (score 0):

Moodle-2.0.2 doesn't seems to have any issues. Can you post the error messages you got when creating the courses?

Several security issues(not related to course creation) were resolved in Moodle-2.1.1 so it's highly recommended to use the latest stable build. Installing Moodle from source is easy and straight forward process, so give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds more like a permissions issue than a moodle version issue.  Ensure you are in either the admin, manager or teacher role, and you should be able to create new courses.